# Typical time to receive approval after App Submission in Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have submitted our app last week and we are yet to hear from Google. Can someone from Google give us an idea of the time frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no approval delay. It may take some time to list and be available in search results. Typically this would happen in 15 minutes.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing asks us to fill the Google form. My app is still not available in market place and it was made public. I cannot write to anyone.